# getting schema attributes from Mongoose Model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose.js to create models with schemas.

I have a list of models (many) and at times I'd like to get the attributes/keys that make up a particular model.

Is there a method to pull out the attribute schemas for any given model?

For example,

```
var mySchema = module.exports = new Schema({
  SID: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
    //, required: true
  },
  teams: {
    type: [String]
  },
  hats: [{
    val: String,
    dt: Date
  }],
  shields: [{
    val: String,
    dt: Date
  }],
  shoes: [{
    val: String,
    dt: Date
  }]
}
```

);

Is it possible to pull out/identify the attributes of the schema `[SID, hats, teams, shields, shoes]`??

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Each schema has a `paths` property, that looks somewhat like this (this is an example of my code):

```
paths: {
    number: [Object],
    'name.first': [Object],
    'name.last': [Object],
    ssn: [Object],
    birthday: [Object],
    'job.company': [Object],
    'job.position': [Object],
    'address.city': [Object],
    'address.state': [Object],
    'address.country': [Object],
    'address.street': [Object],
    'address.number': [Object],
    'address.zip': [Object],
    email: [Object],
    phones: [Object],
    tags: [Object],
    createdBy: [Object],
    createdAt: [Object],
    updatedBy: [Object],
    updatedAt: [Object],
    meta: [Object],
    _id: [Object],
    __v: [Object]
}
```

You can access this through an model too. It's under `Model.schema.paths`.

Comment: could you provide a resource?

Comment: I dont't understand. Do you want links?

Comment: sure... just something that I can reference in the future instead of asking questions here.

Comment: Is there a way to get this from a database object if you don't know the schema?

Comment: Maybe try iterating thru the registered models with [`modelNames()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-modelNames), then you retrieve the models and their paths the same way.

Comment: To add in to the answer , if you have created a Schema named **Temp** then you can access the object using **Temp.paths**

Comment: The tree attribute is better than paths because it includes virtuals.

Comment: It was outdated, please update your answer

Answer (score 52):

Don't have enough rep to comment, but this also spits out a list and loops through all of the schema types.

```
mySchema.schema.eachPath(function(path) {
    console.log(path);
});
```

should print out:

```
number
name.first
name.last
ssn
birthday
job.company
job.position
address.city
address.state
address.country
address.street
address.number
address.zip
email
phones
tags
createdBy
createdAt
updatedBy
updatedAt
meta
_id
__v
```

Or you could get all Attributes as an Array like this:

```
var props = Object.keys(mySchema.schema.paths);
```

Comment: this is not good because it will give you all the attribute of the object, including the methods!

Comment: @e-nouri That is not the behavior I'm getting (at least in v4).  Methods and statics are not included in the `schema.eachPath( )` results

Answer (score 12):

My solution uses mongoose model.

Schema attributes

```
const schema = {
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: 'email is required',
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: 'password is required',
  },
};
```

Schema

```
const FooSchema = new Schema(schema);
```

Model

```
const FooModel = model('Foo', FooSchema);
```

Get attributes from model:

```
Object.keys(FooModel.schema.tree)
```

Result:

```
[
  'email',
  'password',
  '_id',
  '__v'
]
```

Answer (score 8):

Solution for lodash, function which picked all schema properties, excluding specified

```
_.mixin({ pickSchema: function (model, excluded) {
    var fields = [];
    model.schema.eachPath(function (path) {
       _.isArray(excluded) ? excluded.indexOf(path) < 0 ? fields.push(path) : false : path === excluded ? false : fields.push(path);
    });
    return fields;
   }
});

_.pickSchema(User, '_id'); // will return all fields except _id

_.pick(req.body, _.pickSchema(User, ['_id', 'createdAt', 'hidden'])) // all except specified properties
```

read more here https://gist.github.com/styopdev/95f3fed98ce3ebaedf5c

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Schema.prototype.obj** that returns the original object passed to the schema constructor. and you can use it in a utility function to build the object you're going to save.

```js
import Todo from './todoModel'
import { validationResult } from 'express-validator'

const buildObject = (body) => {
    const data = {};
    const keys = Object.keys(Todo.schema.obj);
    keys.forEach(key => { if (body.hasOwnProperty(key)) data[key] = body[key] })
    return data;
}

const create = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) return res.json(errors);
        let toBeSaved = buildObject(req.body);
        const todo = new Todo(toBeSaved);
        const savedTodo = await todo.save();
        if (savedTodo) return res.json(savedTodo);
        return res.json({ 'sanitized': keys })
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ error })
    }
}
```

another way is to to not call the buildObject function and add it in two lines but you will write every key you want to save

```
let { title, description } = req.body;
let toBeSaved = { title, description };
```

Using ES6 shorthand property names

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have only the attributes you added and not the add methods by the ORM that starts with '$___', you have to turn the document into object then access the attributes like this:

```
Object.keys(document.toObject());
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me.
But using Mongoose 5.4.2 I was able to get the keys by doing the following:

```
const mySchema = new Schema({ ... });

const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(mySchema.obj);
```

I'm using **typescript**, however. That might have been the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to have all property values (including nested and populated properties), just use `toObject()` method:

```
let modelAttributes = null;
SomeModel.findById('someId').populate('child.name').exec().then((result) => {
  modelAttributes = result.toObject();
  console.log(modelAttributes);
});
```

The output would be:

```
{
  id: 'someId',
  name: 'someName',
  child: {
    name: 'someChildName'
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the field name you like to get.

```
let fieldName = 'birthday'
console.log(mySchema.schema.paths[fieldName].instance);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over keys aka attributes

```
for (var key in FooModel.schema.obj) {
    //do your stuff with key
}
```