# Sanitizing data before saving to Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a pre handler which sanitizes all data before its written to MongoDB
see: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

I've tried the following to get each property to be able to sanitize it:

```
  blogSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
        var obj = this;
        console.log(obj)//-> https://gist.github.com/daslicht/70e0501acd6c345df8c2

        // I've tried the following to get the single items :
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
            console.log('Keys: ',obj[key]);
        });

        //and:
        for(var key in obj) {
            console.log(obj[key])
        }

        //and:
        _.each( self , function(value, key, list){
            console.log('VALUE:',key);
       })
        next();
    })
```

Any of the above approaches results into something like the following:

Thats the output of:

```
    for(var key in obj) {
       console.log(obj[key])
    }
```

https://gist.github.com/daslicht/cb855f53d86062570a96

Any know how to get each single property so that I can sanitize it, please?

~Marc

[EDIT]
Here is one possible workaround, anyways it would be cleaner to have it directly on Scheme level since this would be more DRY

```
        var post = {
            createdAt : req.body.date,
            createdBy : req.user.username,
            headline : req.body.headline,
            content : req.body.content
        }

        _.each( post , function(value, key, list){
           post[key] =  sanitize(value).xss(); //its the sanetize function of node validator
        })

        var item = new Blog(post);
```

Comment: The source of the outputs seams to be the fact that 'this' is an Instance of the Model. So I need to get the raw data somehow and sanetize it and write it back

Comment: I actually did this using an express middleware. Even more DRY.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I even thought about this, but when using a Express Middleware we either have to add it manually to each route to be protected or ad global middleware. Wouldn't it be nice if we could that direct as Mongoose Plugin?  I am curious, do you like to share your Middleware approach, please?

Comment: unfortunately the xss() function also strips out useful things :/

Comment: @fakewaffle which Express middleware did you use?

Comment: Found this to be useful [express-sanitizer](https://github.com/markau/express-sanitizer), since the xss sanitization is deprecated from express-validator (actually from the node-validator parent module). But a mongoose middleware port of this would be nice, which I haven't found..

Answer (score 4):

You can use [mongoose-sanitizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-sanitizer) plugin, which uses Google Caja to perform the sanitization.

Answer (score 1):

According to [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22341435/1798273), I think you can do

```
blogSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var obj = this;
    blogSchema.schema.eachPath(function(path) {
        SanitizeAndThrowErrorIfNecessary(obj(path), next);
    }); 
    //Validation and Sanitization passed
    next();
})
```

Even if you can set this up successfully, please note that Model.update **will not** trigger pre save hook. Check [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/964)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple way to do it. This uses [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async), but you could refactor it to use a generic JS loop or any other control flow library. The key is to get an array of the document's fields, then you can iterate over those and get/set the values using the current context with `this`. As far as I know, this will ***not*** coerce non-string values into strings. I've tested it with strings, numbers, booleans and objectIds and they are successfully saved as their original data types.

```
yourSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  var self = this;

  // Get the document's fields
  var fields = Object.keys(this._doc);

  // Iteratively sanitize each field
  async.each(fields, function(field, cb) {
    self[field] = validator.escape(self[field]);
    cb();
  }, function(err){
    next();
  });
});
```

Comment: You're not executing any async code. There is no waiting for anything within `validator.escape()` before hitting the callback. No benefit to using this library over any type of normal loop.