# Javascript object Class node

Tags: javascript, object, attributes

this is node base

How do I do get the presentation of the class model, attributes in json/ string format

exemple:
module.exports:{
  attributes: {

```
    user_num: {type: "integer", primaryKey: true},
    contact_id: {type: "integer"},
    username: {type: "string", size: 15},
    pass: {type: "string", size: 20},
```

...
}
i need to give the path of this file as a parametere and the result is a string of the attributes

thank you

Comment: So you just want to serialize your object with JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question doesn't looks very clear to me: assuming you're talking about mongoose models (*but is just a guess*) maybe you can give a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17045236/2689638) if it can help.