# Mongoose get all model instance fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to write a function which takes a model instance and returns all top-level fields declared in this model's schema. I've tried using:

```
function getFields(document)
{
    return Object.keys(document.toObject());
}
```

but this way fields declared in schema but undefined in the document are omitted. So how do I do it?

Comment: They're omitted because they are undefined. You don't want the keys of that instance. because that instance isn't a true representation of the schema

Comment: Check out this question and the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035297/getting-schema-attributes-from-mongoose-model

Comment: Thanks @BrianNoah, it suits my needs.