# How do you validate that a property of a nested document is present when that nested document exists?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

**user.schema.js**

```
var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
var _ = require('lodash');

var userSchema = new Schema({
  local: {
    username: String, // should exist when local exists
    role: String,
    hashedPassword: { type: String, select: false }
  },

  facebook: {
    id: String,
    token: { type: String, select: false }
  },

  twitter: {
    id: String,
    token: { type: String, select: false }
  },

  google: {
    id: String,
    token: { type: String, select: false }
  }
});

userSchema.path('local').validate(function(local) {
  var empty = _.isEmpty(local);
  if (empty) {
    return true;
  }
  else if (!empty && local.username) {
    return true;
  }
  else if (!empty && !local.username) {
    return false;
  }
}, 'Local auth requires a username.');

module.exports = userSchema;
```

I'm trying to validate that `username` is present when `local` isn't empty. Ie. when using local authentication, `username` should be present.

```
// should validate
user = {
  local: {
    username: 'foo';
    hashedPassword: 'sfsdfs'
  }
};

// shouldn't validate
user = {
  local: {
    hashedPassword: 'sdfsdfs'
  }
};

// should validate (because local isn't being used)
user = {
  local: {},
  facebook {
    ...
  }
};
```

I get this error:

```
/Users/azerner/code/mean-starter/server/api/users/user.schema.js:51
userSchema.path('local').validate(function(local) {
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined
```

It seems that you can't get the `path` of objects. I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035297/getting-schema-attributes-from-mongoose-model) that Schemas have a `paths` property. When I `console.log(userSchema.paths)`:

```
{ 'local.username':
   { enumValues: [],
     regExp: null,
     path: 'local.username',
     instance: 'String',
     validators: [],
     setters: [],
     getters: [],
     options: { type: [Function: String] },
     _index: null },
  'local.role':
   { enumValues: [],
     regExp: null,
     path: 'local.role',
     instance: 'String',
     validators: [],
     setters: [],
     getters: [],
     options: { type: [Function: String] },
     _index: null },
  'local.hashedPassword':
   { enumValues: [],
     regExp: null,
     path: 'local.hashedPassword',
     instance: 'String',
     validators: [],
     setters: [],
     getters: [],
     options: { type: [Function: String], select: false },
     _index: null,
     selected: false },
  'facebook.id':
   { enumValues: [],
     regExp: null,
     path: 'facebook.id',
     instance: 'String',
     validators: [],
     setters: [],
     getters: [],
     options: { type: [Function: String] },
     _index: null },
  'facebook.token':
   { enumValues: [],
     regExp: null,
     path: 'facebook.token',
     instance: 'String',
     validators: [],
     setters: [],
     getters: [],
     options: { type: [Function: String], select: false },
     _index: null,
     selected: false },
  'twitter.id':
   { enumValues: [],
     regExp: null,
     path: 'twitter.id',
     instance: 'String',
     validators: [],
     setters: [],
     getters: [],
     options: { type: [Function: String] },
     _index: null },
  'twitter.token':
   { enumValues: [],
     regExp: null,
     path: 'twitter.token',
     instance: 'String',
     validators: [],
     setters: [],
     getters: [],
     options: { type: [Function: String], select: false },
     _index: null,
     selected: false },
  'google.id':
   { enumValues: [],
     regExp: null,
     path: 'google.id',
     instance: 'String',
     validators: [],
     setters: [],
     getters: [],
     options: { type: [Function: String] },
     _index: null },
  'google.token':
   { enumValues: [],
     regExp: null,
     path: 'google.token',
     instance: 'String',
     validators: [],
     setters: [],
     getters: [],
     options: { type: [Function: String], select: false },
     _index: null,
     selected: false },
  _id:
   { path: '_id',
     instance: 'ObjectID',
     validators: [],
     setters: [ [Function: resetId] ],
     getters: [],
     options: { type: [Object], auto: true },
     _index: null,
     defaultValue: [Function: defaultId] } }
```

So it seems that paths like `local.username` and `facebook.token` exist, but not "top level" paths like `local` and `facebook`.

If I try to validate the `local.username` path, it doesn't work like I want it to.

```
userSchema.path('local.username').validate(function(username) {
  return !!username
}, 'Local auth requires a username.');
```

The validation is only applied when `local.username` exists. I want to *validate that it exists*. So when it doesn't exist, the validation isn't applied, and thus it's considered valid and gets saved.

I also tried the following approach, but the outcome is the same as the `local.username` approach (validation doesn't get hit when the username isn't present, and it gets labeled as valid).

```
var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
var _ = require('lodash');

var userSchema = new Schema({
  local: {
    username: {
      type: String,
      validate: [validateUsernameRequired, 'Local auth requires a username.']
    },
    role: String,
    hashedPassword: { type: String, select: false }
  },

  facebook: {
    id: String,
    token: { type: String, select: false }
  },

  twitter: {
    id: String,
    token: { type: String, select: false }
  },

  google: {
    id: String,
    token: { type: String, select: false }
  }
});

function validateUsernameRequired(username) {
  return !!username;
}

module.exports = userSchema;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adam, why don't you try a pre-validate hook that conditionally passes an error to the next function. I think this'll give you the flexibility you're looking for. Let me know if it doesn't work.

For example

```
schema.pre('validate', function(next) {
  if(/*your error case */){ next('validation error text') }
  else { next() }
})
```

This will cause mongoose to send a `ValidationError` back to whoever tried to save the document.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create a custom validation. Not sure if you implemented everything you need for it. It looks like this:

```
// make sure every value is equal to "something"
function validator (val) {
  return val == 'something';
}
new Schema({ name: { type: String, validate: validator }});

// with a custom error message

var custom = [validator, 'Uh oh, {PATH} does not equal "something".']
new Schema({ name: { type: String, validate: custom }});

// adding many validators at a time

var many = [
    { validator: validator, msg: 'uh oh' }
  , { validator: anotherValidator, msg: 'failed' }
]
new Schema({ name: { type: String, validate: many }});

// or utilizing SchemaType methods directly:

var schema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });
schema.path('name').validate(validator, 'validation of `{PATH}` failed with 
value `{VALUE}`');
```

here is the link: [mongoose custom validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate)