# How do you set a schema property to be of type SubDocument in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to do something like this:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  local: localSchema,
  facebook: facebookSchema,
  twitter: twitterSchema,
  google: googleSchema
});
```

But it seems that a Schema is not a valid [SchemaType](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

In the SubDocuments [guide](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html), they only give an example where the child schema is put inside of an array, but that isn't what I want to do.

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  children: [childSchema]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just trying to create a sub object for each of those properties. You can accomplish this one of two ways.

#### Embedded in the schema itself

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    local: {
        someProperty: {type: String}
        //More sub-properties...
    }
    //More root level properties
});
```

#### Reusable object to be used in multiple schemas

```
//this could be defined in a separate module and exported for reuse
var localObject = {
    someProperty: {type: String}
    //more properties
}

var userSchema = new Schema({
    local: localObject
});

var someOtherSchema = new Schema({
    test: localObject
});
```

Comment: I had previously tried approach 1 (approach 2 isn't what I'm trying to do). I had [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086455/how-do-you-validate-that-a-property-of-a-nested-document-is-present-when-that-ne) problem and was looking for an alternative. I was hoping that if I used localSchema that I could just use use `require: true` and have it work the way I expect.