# How to get only required fileds from Mongoose Schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm looking for a way to send a custom error message to the client when a required input is not set.

A sample Mongoose Schema:

```
this._schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    }
});
```

I use a `this._schema.pre('validate')` function to test if a required input is missing and, if it is missing, pass a custom `AppError` to my `next()` function which will handle the rest.

The pre-validation:

```
this._schema.pre('validate', function(next) {
    if(!this.email) return next(new AppError('Email not set'));
    next();
});
```

I don't want to check for each field manually using a list of `if` statements. Rather I would like to loop over all required fields and throw the error if one of them is missing (loop should be recursive too for nested fields).

**Question:
How can I loop over required fields and pass the first missing field to an Error?**

*Note: I'm not sure if this is the right way, so other interpretations are welcome! Found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035297/getting-schema-attributes-from-mongoose-model), but I'm not sure that's the correct answer.*